# scrollTo() function does nothing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scrollbar

I wanted to scroll to the bottom of the page using vanilla JS, but I encountered a problem. The code below is supposed to scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Whereas all it does is logs "undefined" in the console. Inputting

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

returns an integer 736. Other than that, it doesn't matter what I input into the function's parameters, nothing happens. What more, it only happens on one website. What may matter (not sure) is that the website hides its vertical scrolling bar, even thought it has a really long list of content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the actuall scroll that you have on the website is not the scroll of the `body` but a scroll of another element inside that body.

Here is an example:

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
});
$('#btn2').click(function() {
  el = $('.a')[0];
  el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.a {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.b {
  height: 1500px;
  position: relative;
}
div.c {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <button id="btn1">Scroll body - doesn't work</button><br />
    <button id="btn2">Scroll element - will work</button>
    <div class="c">This is at bottom of page</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note - the usage of `jquery` is only to make the example shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Put some content in your page o style the body heigth = 1500px for example,  then try to execute same code.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved. This is what had to be done:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display = "block";
```

For whatever reason, changing the display to "block" enabled the scrolling using the given code:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will try to type in browser's console like a var a = 5 you also will get undefined. It happens that your example and my did not return anything.